# CoreServices.h file not found in portaudio build on macOS 10.11 Xcode 8.0

Tags: frameworks, portaudio, core-services

This is called though cocoa.h and foundation.h, then NSURLError.h.  Not sure why this compiler error just came up when I added portaudio and some other needed frameworks.  The error first comes from some existing code.  Indeed, there is no CoreServices/CoreServices.h anywhere on the whole system.  Do I need to update Xcode?

I found an Apple help answer that said "Those are not makefile directives. How are you trying to build it? Most projects like this come with "configure" scripts that you just need to run from the command line. The only thing you need from Xcode are the Command Line Tools."  I don't know what this means or how to do this.

I did run the port audio/configure terminal script, but saw nothing about CoreServices.h being generated.  Where does this need to come from?

Thanks.

I further note that in the CoreServices frameworks directory associated with the Xcode project, there is a terminal file called "CoreServices" that when run, generates the error "CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices: cannot execute binary file"  .  What could it be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question in this specific case but:

1. I believe that `CoreServices.h` can be found at `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Headers/CoreServices.h`, is it not the case on your machine? If not, you might have to re-install Xcode
2. To install *PortAudio*, you can also use [brew](http://brew.sh) with the command `brew install portaudio` and then link your project with its headers and libs (`/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/include` and `/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.6.0/lib`) in your Xcode project (under the tab *Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries*). That might be the easiest option.